# Function in the half of arrow with tikzcd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I'd like to do a diagram in which a function f appears in the half of the arrow, like this:

[image]

Is it possible doing this with tikzcd package?

Comment: The example at the end of section 2 of the manual has `\arrow{r}[description]{\phi}`

Answer (score 4):

The label to an arrow is, by default, placed above the arrow (move your head or the paper so that the arrow goes from West to East, to know what ‘above’ means).

You can use the `[swap]` option before the label for setting it below the arrow:

```
\arrow{r}[swap]{\phi}
```

will place the phi below the arrow. In order to place the label in a hole in the middle of the arrow, use `description`:

```
\arrow{r}[description]{\phi}
```

Comment: How about place the label in a hole not in the middle of the arrow, but in some place e.g. 0.7 times the length of the arrow?

Comment: @Lao-tzu With the “old” syntax, `\arrow{r}[description,pos=0.7]{\phi}`; with the “modern” syntax, `\arrow[r,"\phi" description,pos=0.7]`. You can also use `near start` or `near end` in place of `pos=<fraction>`.